# Adding a tip to button when button active in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, tooltip

[image]

[image]

How add tip to second image when it is active. I have tried this [example](http://www.red-team-design.com/css3-tooltips) to display tip but i not helped my requirement.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Please make a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) on what you did, so we can help you from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<div id="pointed"> Arrow </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#pointed {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;color:white
}

#pointed::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 30%;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 10px black;
    border-left: solid 10px transparent;
    border-right: solid 10px transparent;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mqat9/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

<div id="pointed"> <a href="#">Arrow </a></div>

#pointed {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: black;color:white
          }

#pointed:active::after {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 45%;
content: '';
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: solid 10px black;
border-left: solid 10px transparent;
border-right: solid 10px transparent;
}
```